# Why are the righteous taken away from the evil to come?

Tags: isaiah, jeremiah, ecclesiastes

Isaiah 57:1 (KJV)

> The righteous perisheth, and no man layeth it to heart: and merciful
> men are taken away, none considering that the righteous is taken away
> from the evil to come.

Why are the righteous taken away from the evil to come? Furthermore, why speak of the righteous as being "taken away"? Is "the evil to come" a reference to "the day of evil" that is spoken of in Jeremiah 17:17,18? If not, then how or why is this evil different from evil that is already evident?

Ecclesiates 6:1 (KJV)

> There is an evil which I have seen under the sun, and it is common
> among men:

Answer (score 2):

Let us be very clear about the most important point:

> John 16:33 - I have said these things to you, that in me you may have
> peace. **In the world you will have tribulation**. But take heart; I
> have overcome the world.”

> John 15:20, 21 - Remember the word that I spoke to you: ‘No servant is
> greater than his master.’ If they persecuted Me, **they will persecute
> you as well**; ...

See also Luke 21:12-19, Matt 24:9-13, 2 Thess 1:4, 5, etc.  God's people should expect to be persecuted and have troubles in this world.

However, this is not the subject of Isaiah 57:1 -

> The righteous perish, and no one takes it to heart; devout men are
> swept away, while no one considers that the righteous are guided from
> the presence of evil.

While the people of God are to expect troubles, sometimes God spares people from difficulties that might presumably be too much to bare of for other reasons known only to divine wisdom.  Note the instruction in 1 Cor 10:13 -

> No temptation has seized you except what is common to man. And God is
> faithful; He will not let you be tempted beyond what you can bear. But
> when you are tempted, He will also provide an escape, so that you can
> stand up under it.

Occasionally, that "way of escape" is death.  In the next life we will be delighted with the way God has lead us during our earthly lives.  Ellicott appears to agree:

> (1) The righteous perisheth . . .—The words seem written as if in the
> anticipation or in the actual presence of Manasseh’s persecution of
> the true prophets. Even before that persecution burst out in its full
> violence, the “righteous” survivors of Hezekiah’s régime may well have
> vexed their souls even to death with the evils that were around them.
> The prophet finds comfort in the thought that their death was a
> deliverance from yet worse evils. The singular number points to the
> few conspicuous sufferers.

The Cambridge commentary is similar:

> **merciful men**: lit., men of piety (cf. ch. Isaiah 55:7, Isaiah 28:14).
>
> **none considering that the righteous is taken away from the evil to come** The idea conveyed by this rendering is that the natural death
> of many good men was a divine intimation, little heeded by the
> community, that some great calamity was impending.

Comment: Great use of 1 Cor. 10:13, +1

Comment: Agreed it is common to experience affliction and trouble in this world, but I am not persuaded the best meaning here is "guided from the presence of evil."  Namely because most references (aside from the BSB) to "guiding" emphasize the (one) direction towards good or right, not the path away from (or avoidance of a particular, coming) evil.  Furthermore, the "evil to come" probably hasn't received enough attention.  I think this, because "taken away" seems to be more frequently translated and understood as being "gathered" - which might be perceived as being something other than "by death."

Comment: @Hugs - "gathered to his people" is a Hebrew idiom for death, Deut 32:50, Num 20:24, Gen 35:29, 49:33, 25:8, 17, etc.

Comment: @Dottard - okay, good to know... however, when used with the nuance of death it always appears (at least, what I have seen thus far) to be set in the phrase "gathered to [unto, or with]" either his people, my people, their fathers, thy household, or thy grave ... except here in Isaiah 57:1.  So, I think... why is that? Does it not leave open the possibility of something more subtle and/or deeper? Some other purpose or meaning when it is parsed from said phrase, as is the case in Gen. 49:1 (and most anywhere else.)